# Prove interval of convergence for the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)!}{k^k} x^{k-1}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Consider the following Taylor series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)!}{k^k} x^{k-1}$$

Numerical experiments suggest that the series converges on the interval:

$$x\in (-e,e)$$

Disclaimer

I'm not sure how to prove this.

I guessed the following integral representation:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)!}{k^k} x^{k-1}=\int_0^\infty \frac{dt}{e^t-xt}$$

Now we can kind of 'prove' the convergence interval.

$$e^t>xt$$

$$x<\frac{e^t}{t}$$

$$\min \frac{e^t}{t}=e$$

It's pretty obvious that the integral converges for all $x<e$ and diverges for $x=e$.

> How to prove that the series diverges for $x>e$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with Stirling's approximation?

Comment: @BrianJ.Diaz, yes, I thought about it right after posting. But I would like a more general proof, without relying on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the ratio test:  if $a_n$ is the $n$th term of the series, then
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\cdot\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot\lvert x\rvert\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}\cdot\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}\cdot\lvert x\rvert\\
&=e^{-1}\lvert x\rvert.
\end{align*}
$$
So, by the Ratio test, this series converges when $\lvert x\rvert<e$, diverges when $\lvert x\rvert>e$, and the behavior is indeterminant when $\lvert x\rvert=e$.

Comment: Ah, right you are.  Whoops.  Will fix quick.

Comment: It is also a good exercise to actually see what the series does at those endpoints...The OP states that $e$ is not included in the Interval Of Convergence, but I am not so sure...

Comment: Thanks, the ratio test is the most fundamental. So, the main question answered

Comment: @imranfat, I had something stupid about $-\infty$ in the OP - obviously, the series would not converge for large negative $x$, but the integral does? What's up with that?

Comment: The integral $\int\frac{1}{2^x}dx$ converges on such an interval,say $(0,\infty)$ but the given series (which is a geometric series)
$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{x^k}$ that doesn't have such an interval of convergence for $x$. An interval of convergence for a series is just not the same as an interval for which an (improper) intergral is convergent.

Comment: If $x = -e$ then the series is convergent according to Leibniz criterion for alternating series. (The sequence $a_{k}= \dfrac{(k-1)!}{k^{k}}e^{k}$ is decreasing
and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{k} = 0$.)
If $x = e$ then the series is not convergent. (Compare the given series with the positive series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.)